# Acessing a MySQL table (or view) from MS SQL Server

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

It is possible to access some data in some table (or view) in a MySQL server from an MS SQL Server 2012?

I have a query in SQLserver but i need to get some info from a table in other database.. is it possible?

thanks

Comment: Why dont you make a dump of that table and put in on the other server(with the required adjustements) so all data is in once place.

Comment: [HOWTO: Setup SQL Server Linked Server to MySQL](http://www.ideaexcursion.com/2009/02/25/howto-setup-sql-server-linked-server-to-mysql/)

Comment: Yep, we use the linked server method for loading data from MySQL and have found it to generally be pretty reliable